# Disply flex order CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a grid that will display many divs with content. At the moment, it is in 2 rows, splitting the divs 50% height.

This is correct, however it is in the following order:-

```
1,3,5, 7,9,11
2,4,6, 8,10,12
```

However I would like it to show the following way:-

```
1,2,3, 7,8,9
4,5,6, 10,11,12
```

I would like to keep the horizontal scroll in place, so it only shows 2 divs per row.

Ideally, I do not want to add any extra divs if possible, I need to just change the order. I also want it to show the first 6 posts, so 1,2,3,4,5,6. I have made a codepen here:- https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/bGdXEVw

```css
.tiles {
  height: 1000px;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

.tiles {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* transform: rotateX(180deg); */
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(1n) {
  flex-basis: calc(50%);
  background: red !important;
}

.tiles .tile {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* transform: rotateX(180deg); */
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile">1</div>
  <div class="tile">2</div>
  <div class="tile">3</div>
  <div class="tile">4</div>
  <div class="tile">5</div>
  <div class="tile">6</div>
  <div class="tile">7</div>
  <div class="tile">8</div>
  <div class="tile">9</div>
  <div class="tile">10</div>
  <div class="tile">11</div>
  <div class="tile">12</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if you see the codpen this should make sense

Comment: @Brad without changing the HTML? You can use the `order` property.

Comment: So you basically want all the divs to have a `row` output, but then want each group of six to be in a column (essentially)?

Comment: Yes correct, so it shows 1,2,3 on the first row at the top, with 4,5,6 at the bottom. Then this repeats

Comment: @symlink is there a dynamic way to do this? As their could be 100's of divs

Comment: @Brad depends on the layout of the flex items. You're better off creating an HTML structure (static or dynamic) that more closely resembles your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using CSS grid easily:

```css
.tiles {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
  grid-auto-columns:calc((100% - 20px)/3);
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  grid-gap:10px;
  overflow: auto;
  counter-reset:num 0;
}

.tiles .tile {
  background: red;
  font-size:50px;
  color:#fff;
  grid-row:1;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 4),
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 5),
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 6){
  grid-row:2;
  background:blue;
}

.tiles .tile:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work, if the elements weren't dynamic. The problem will be the grid row assigning `.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 4),
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 5),
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 6)` unless OP adds a bunch of rules to cover up to 100s of items. Still gave an upvote, because it's good exercise in `nth` selectors.

Comment: @disinfor this already cover 100 or even more items no need to add more rules. You can see that it's working fine until 24 elements in my example and you can add as many as you want

Comment: OH! You're right! I tested it in an incorrect way. My upvote definitely stands. This is a great approach. For OP, this also works if you have less than 24 items.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Temani!! I really need to up my CSS grid knowledge, thank again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `order` property for each element.

There might be a better way to set up the `order` number, but manually it looks like this:

```css
.tiles {
  height: 1000px;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

.tiles {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* transform: rotateX(180deg); */
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(1n) {
  flex-basis: calc(50%);
  background: red !important;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(2) {
  order: 3;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(3) {
  order: 5;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(6) {
  order: 6;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(7) {
  order: 7;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(8) {
  order: 9;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(9) {
  order: 9;
}


.tiles .tile:nth-child(10) {
  order: 10;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(11) {
  order: 11;
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(12) {
  order: 12;
}

.tiles .tile {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* transform: rotateX(180deg); */
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile">1</div>
  <div class="tile">2</div>
  <div class="tile">3</div>
  <div class="tile">4</div>
  <div class="tile">5</div>
  <div class="tile">6</div>
  <div class="tile">7</div>
  <div class="tile">8</div>
  <div class="tile">9</div>
  <div class="tile">10</div>
  <div class="tile">11</div>
  <div class="tile">12</div>
</div>
```

Edit: Since you're using WordPress, you can use the `modulo` operator to count the posts and wrap every six posts: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

SAMPLE QUERY (since I don't know what yours looks like):

```
if ( have_posts ) :
    // This is how many posts your query found
    $post_count = $wp_query->found_posts;
    // Setup an iterator to count posts;
    $i = 0;
    // start the loop.  
    while ( have_posts ) : the_post; 

        // This is where we check the posts to wrap.
        // Basically, if the iterator returns the remainder of 0 using 6 as the divider
        if ( $i%6 === 0 ) :
            echo '<div class="post-wrapper">';
        endif;

        /* ALL OF YOUR POST OUTPUT CODE GOES HERE */

        // Check the iterator again to add the closing wrapping div tag.
        // If the remainder is 5, that means it will be the last item in the loop or
        // if the total count minus 1, that means we are at the end of all posts.
        if ( $i%6 === 5 || $i === ( $post_count - 1 ) ) :
            echo '</div><!-- /post-wrapper -->';
        endif;

        // increment the iterator up one every time we loop.
        $i++;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

I didn't test with the actual WP loop, but did test on an array and got the output as expected. With the wrapped content, you can then change your CSS to keep the horizontal scroll, but you can use the blocks of posts as a flex element.

Comment: Is there a dynamic way to do this? As their will be 100's of divs

Comment: I'm looking into that now. How are you outputting this code? Is there potential to add information to the `title` div markup? Also, update your question with the dynamic requirement.

Comment: You can see the blogs on this page:- http://www.project-progress.co.uk/intersystems-phase2/category/business/

Comment: Looks like you're using WordPress and you can alter the code on the posts. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct. not sure how to do this though by splitting it!

Comment: I think you might be approaching this wrong - since there's not really a good dynamic way to do what you're asking with CSS alone. What are you using to output the posts? `WP_Query` or some other custom loop, as this would be a really good case for an `if/else` situation to group your posts into groups of 6.

Comment: Hi @disinfor thanks for your help! Yes I am using WP_Query to pull through all the posts

Comment: @Brad I added some code you can use on your loop to change the actual markup to wrap groups of 6 posts.

Comment: Unfortunately the loop was breaking the site, but thanks for your help on this and showing me a route I could use, really appreciate it